# Python: Sqlite multiple inserts with only one disk operation

Tags: python, sqlite, python-shove

I am having some [disk problems](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19) when deploying to a docker instance and I can't figure out yet how to solve it.

In the docker instance, there is a process that uses [Shove](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shove/) with sqlite as the backend to save data to disk as a dictionary (I am saving around 200'000 records).

The problem occurs because I am using Shove as a dictionary to save, which makes every `__setitem__` operation into a insert in sqlite.

Now Shove offers a `sync` (an integer) parameter to specify when to execute the actual storage into disk, but that only saves a temporary dictionary in memory, and when the time comes it still makes the number of `sync` operations into disk (which I don't want).

I checked that sqlite offers a [`executemany`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.executemany) operation which should reduce the method-call overheads, but does it really does 1 (or at least close to 1) operations to disk? I can't seem to find a clear explanation for this.

I also checked that a [bulk operation could be done on sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) but it isn't explained on python, so should I just call it with `execute` and creating a very big string? (I want to be able to at least save 1000 records at a time).

So what should be the best way to write to disk with the minimum amount of operations?